# Servlets beginner

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans

I am studying a Java EE course at the moment and I am on the module with servlets.

Included in the course are simple sample servlets.

This may sound dumb but I cant get any of them to work either by themselves or in netbeans on the glassfish server.
I have tried dropiing them in the web pages folder in the project and also I replaced the content of the index.jsp file with WelcomeServlet.html content.
The example I will use her is the first one and the most simple called WelcomeServlet.

The function of the servlet is that when the user pressed the "get html document" button the program should retrieve the document from the .java file.
However when I press the button I get this error

HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
type Status report

messageNot Found

descriptionThe requested resource is not available.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0

***Here is the code in question.
WelcomeServlet.html***

```
    <?xml version = "1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<!-- Fig. 17.6: WelcomeServlet.html -->

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>Handling an HTTP Get Request</title>
</head>

<body>
   <form action = "/advjhtp1/welcome1" method = "get">

      <p><label>Click the button to invoke the servlet
         <input type = "submit" value = "Get HTML Document" />
      </label></p>

   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WelcomeServlet.java**

```
// Fig. 16.5: WelcomeServlet.java
// A simple servlet to process get requests.
package com.deitel.advjhtp1.servlets;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet {   

   // process "get" requests from clients
   protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response )
         throws ServletException, IOException 
   {
      response.setContentType( "text/html" );
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

      // send XHTML page to client

      // start XHTML document
      out.println( "<?xml version = \"1.0\"?>" );

      out.println( "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD " +
         "XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org" +
         "/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">" ); 

      out.println( 
         "<html xmlns = \"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">" );

      // head section of document
      out.println( "<head>" );
      out.println( "<title>A Simple Servlet Example</title>" );
      out.println( "</head>" );

      // body section of document
      out.println( "<body>" );
      out.println( "<h1>Welcome to Servlets!</h1>" );
      out.println( "</body>" );

      // end XHTML document
      out.println( "</html>" );
      out.close();  // close stream to complete the page
   }   
}
```

If anyone out there can get this code running please help me to do the same.

Comment: Show us your `web.xml`. Also, it is considered bad practice to put HTML markup in Java code.

Comment: Buy a good servlet book like `Head First Servlets`.

Comment: for basic examples just out.println( "<h1>Welcome to Servlets!</h1>" ); will work ! . try that , and just add a SOP to check if a method is getting called

Comment: There is no web.xml file.

Comment: @John How is your servlet configured? Where and to what url is it mapped?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'm doing a java course. I don't know what a SOP is. Also I want it to contain the button as I need to use this to complete an assignment. Can you get this to work as is?

Comment: @john A SOP is a `System.out.println() statement.

Comment: I'm trying to run it as a java web application in netbeans. So I don't do any mapping. I'm trying to run it on the glassfish server locally.

Comment: So this is one of many examples with the module. This is all that is contained in the file. I think I am meant to be able to use these files as is.

Comment: The welcomeServlet.html works fine. Appears in the browser but when I press the button it doesn't "get" the java file.

Comment: Basically these two are not interacting with each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code. Indeed nothing wrong in the java code. Probably just incorrect action path.

Full project:

Project name:  TestServlet

WelcomeServlet.html:

```
 <form action = "MyWelcomeServlet" method = "get">
```

web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
    <description>Welcome Servlet</description>
    <display-name>Welcome Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.deitel.advjhtp1.servlets.WelcomeServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyWelcomeServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Run it:

```
http://localhost:8080/TestServlet/WelcomeServlet.html
```

Click the button and it will run the servlet (you can try running the direct link to the servlet) which is:

```
http://localhost:8080/TestServlet/MyWelcomeServlet
```

(I prefix "My" before the servlet url-pattern so that you do not confuse between the servlet and the html link).  Normally it is bad practice to give same name to the servlet and the html/jsp file.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your Web application project, you should have a folder called `WEB-INF` and in it you should have a file called `web.xml`. If you don't, create it and put it there. This is known as the Deploymenet Descriptor. You can read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs70/webapp/webappdeployment.html).

It should contain at least the following

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5"> // or another version
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.deitel.advjhtp1.servlets.WelcomeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

You should then navigate to

```
localhost:XXXX/welcome
```

where XXXX is the Glassfish port, to view your page.

You can also do the above [with annotations](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/10/14/introduction-to-servlet-3.html), if your container supports servlet 3.0.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did what you said and the servlet works. Howver it only opens the .java file which says welcomeServlets!. It doesn't open the .html file and allow the user to press the button. So the it now skips the .html file and just runs the .java file. I am hopping to get the it run as it is supposed to

Answer (score -1):

You get a 404 not found because simply the form points to an incorrect path. So it can not find the servlet to submit to.

Your servlet class is "WelcomeServlet.java" in the package com.deitel.advjhtp1.servlets

So in the HTML, the path should be:

```
< form action = "com.deitel.advjhtp1.servlets.WelcomeServlet" method = "get">
```

Comment: <form action = "com.deitel.advjhtp1.servlets.WelcomeServlet" method = "get">

Comment: What does a form `action` attribute have to do with a servlet's fully qualified class name?

Comment: Sorry I put it wrong. The path you put in form action depends on how the servlet is mapped in the web.xml. You should try to config the web.xml as in Sotirios Delimanolis's answer. Then you can simply use:  <form action="welcome" ....>

Comment: I did do that and netbeans did load the .java servlet file but not the .html file. So basically it skipped the page with the button which is really the whole point of this example.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with the code. I yhink may be you misunderstand the point of the code. What you receive after clicking the button is not a "html file" but will be a servlet which output "html content" (in this case a welcome message). On the address bar will still be the sevlet url, not any "html file".

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to contribute. I know that's what's meant to happen when I press the button but instead I get an error page saying the page could not be found. So far I can either get the button without the servlet or the servlet without the button. Have you tried to get this code to work in netbeans? If you have and succeeded please tell me how you did it.